# Introductory references for Morse theory

Tags: reference-request, morse-theory

In view of my master's thesis, I have to learn the basics of Morse theory (defining the morse complex, showing that Morse homology is isomorphic to singular homology...)

I have been told that Milnor's books about Morse theory and the h-cobordism theorem could be a good place to start looking. What are your opinions about these books? And what are possible alternatives?

Comment: My opinion about Milnor's books is that they are some of the finest mathematical writing of the last century.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's my opinion, too. It's also probably the opinion of many others!

Comment: In either of the sources you mentioned, there is no explicit definition of Morse homology. Instead Milnor (in the 2nd? chapter of Morse Theory) shows every closed manifold has the homotopy type of a CW-complex using explicit deformation retractions. This CW-complex is the Morse complex (it is not given this name in the text if I remember), and the attaching maps and cells are the same as the chain maps and groups of the chain complex defined in Morse homology (say from the wikipedia article on it).

Comment: @PVAL I haven't read Milnor's book *Morse Theory* yet, but I'm reading the book by Audin and Damien given in the answer below, which is really good IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of books which I like (other than Milnor, of course):

- [*Morse Theory and Floer Homology*, Audin, Michèle, Damian, Mihai](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-1-4471-5495-2)
- [*An Introduction to Morse Theory (Translations of Mathematical Monographs, Vol. 208)*, Yukio Matsumoto](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821810227)
- [*An Invitation to Morse Theory*, Nicolaescu, Liviu](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-1-4614-1104-8?wt_mc=PPC.Google+AdWords.EPR653-GoogleShopping_Product_EN&otherVersion=978-1-4614-1105-5)

Comment: Thanks! The first one in particular seems good, and I can have it for free through my university via SpringerLink :)

Answer (score 2):

The recommendations above are very nice. I would like to add the following paper by Joa Weber

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411465

It is not a book, but it is a very nice exposition of the Morse complex. He shows the basic results of the theory through dynamical systems methods.

Comment: Thanks. Useful reference.